# CA: Suppress results from generated code not working in VS2010 beta 2

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I'm trying to run codeanalysis on an assembly that contains an entity model (edmx file). In project properties I have checked the "Suppress results from generated code" option, but I am still getting a lot of CA errors pertaining to the auto-generated EF code.

Has anyone experienced this? And is there a work-around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, "Suppress results from generated code" really means "Don't look at types with `GeneratedCodeAttribute`". EF's code generator hasn't added this, historically (though I've suggested it to the team). But *you* can add it if you [use custom T4](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx).

Comment: That explains it then. Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you update the model? you have to add the attribute again?

Comment: @Juan, no, you only need to change the T4 once.

Answer (score 11):

Just put the attribute on your class definition.

But how to do it, since your file can get overridden any time. Use a separate file, since all generated classes are partial classes. Open a separate file, and write something like:

```
[GeneratedCode("EntityModelCodeGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class YourEntitiesContextName : ObjectContext
{
}
```

This will skip code analysis on your particular generated class. StyleCop for instance is more smart and doesn't touch files that have `.designer/.generated` part in their name or regions that have `generated` word in their name.

Comment: Doing this will stop FxCop from checking any custom code you add, though. The EF does it on every individual property, instead, so that custom code is still checked.

Comment: @Craig: That's true. But since this is my T$ and I know I'm not adding additional code to my classes that is fine. But point taken. Very valuable comment. +1 for that.